# Android - high fps drop with OpenGL ES 1.1

Tags: android, opengl-es

I am trying to make a simple 2D game. I have noticed that the onDrawFrame() function is called in 60 FPS with vsync. However for some reason on older devices if rendering time exceeds 1ms then it will skip a frame every few frame and the animation doesn't look smooth at all. And I am talking about devices that aren't too old...

90% of the drawing code looks like this:

```
        gl.glBindTexture(GL11.GL_TEXTURE_2D, MainProgram.glSurfaceView.renderer.ResourceIdToTexture(R.drawable.tank));
        gl.glFrontFace(GL11.GL_CW);
        gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, vertexBuffer);
        gl.glTexCoordPointer(2, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, tankTextureBuffer);
        float[] glCoords = World.WorldCoordsToGLCoords(tank.GetPosition().PosX(), tank.GetPosition().PosY());
        float[] glDims = {0.025f, 0.025f};
        gl.glPushMatrix(); 
        gl.glTranslatef(glCoords[0], glCoords[1]+glDims[1], -1.0f);
        gl.glScalef(glDims[0], glDims[1], 1.0f);
        float[] tc = tank.GetOwner().GetColor().asFloatArray();
        gl.glColor4f(tc[0],tc[1],tc[2],tc[3]);
        gl.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, vertex.length / 3);
        gl.glColor4f(1f, 1f, 1f, 1f);
        gl.glPopMatrix();
```

Still, it took 1 millisecond to process all of the drawings to the screen and I have noticed that the FPS (I have measured the number of timer per second the surfaceView.drawFrame is called) drops from 60 to around 30 and it looks almost disgusting.
How do other games have such smooth animations even on the oldest devices?
And how do I achieve this with GLES11?

Comment: How do you measure time to get 1ms ? Chances are that this timing is purely CPU related, and the time needed by the GPU to render your frame is much higher.

Comment: I used System.nanoTime() to measure the time it took from the beginning of drawFrame() to its end. I also added a counter that nullifies itself every second to measure how often is this function called by GLThread. Maybe the GL calls aren't really working right away and there's more to it..

Comment: That's not a valid way for measuring the time it takes to render. In a VSYNC'd application the operation of swapping buffers flushes your command buffer (e.g. does all the rendering), then blocks the calling thread until the begin of a new VBLANK interval at which point it swaps the back/front buffers. If you really want to know the performance more accurately, try manually flushing and measuring the time *after* doing that, and ***then*** swapping buffers. It's still not as accurate as using timer queries in pure OpenGL, but it's better than what you're trying right now.

Comment: Ok, and what about the general question? How much time does a draw take for today's games that make it absolutely smooth while drawing around 10 bitmaps with the above code divides the fps by 2? And how do you make rendering that fast?